# jQuery mobile not working with Jquery Validation Engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validation-engine

I am using `Jquery validation Engine` with `Jquery Mobile`, it works fine when refresh the page but didn't work when coming from `index page` to `abc page`.

I have tried below code but no progress also I changed `pageinit` to `pagebeforeshow` but still no progress.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){

});
```

My console says:

```
TypeError: options is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

options.eventTrigger = "submit";
```

The above error comes in `Jquery validation engine` file, but once `refresh` it works like charm.

Any help will be greatly appricaited.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function(){

});
```